# "looking forward to" vs" look forward to"

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between "I am looking forward to interviewing with your company" versus "I look forward to interview with your company"?

Comment: Yes, Ash is correct. You'll want "interviewing" for both sentences. And, if I may, as a stylistic matter I would remove "with" and just leave "interviewing." Unless, of course, you mean to say "I am looking forward to being interviewed by your company." I don't think that is the case, though.

Comment: Two different things matter there.

There are differences between "I am looking forward to interviewing with your company" and "I look forward to an interview with your company" and first, please, could you re-phrase either idea to be more grammatical?

In modern English - never you mind traditional meanings -  "I am looking forward to interviewing…” is acceptable; in no way different to "I look forward to interviewing…”

Answer (score 1):

No, not really, the second is perhaps slightly more formal, you'll want interview*ing* in both cases though.